# Pages not processing fully

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape news articles from yahoo finance and to do so, i want to use their sitemap page  https://finance.yahoo.com/sitemap/

The problem i have is that after following a link https://finance.yahoo.com/sitemap/2015_04_02 for example scrapy does not process the whole page - only the header. So i cannot access the links to the different articles.
Is there some internal requests that i have to sent to the page  ?

I still get the whole page by deactivating javascript in my browser and i use scrapy 1.6

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check page view in scrapy shell - how does scrapy "sees" it?

Comment: Yes that is how i know scrapy only process the header.

Comment: Above URL perfectly works for me. Can you post your code here? Also what did you mean by "header"?

Comment: The first url works fine. The second one i only get the top of the page with the "home mail etc" as well ad the search form but the content of the page does not load. I use a linkextractor with allow='news' in my code but the articles links are not there.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Some sites take defensive measures against robots scraping their websites. If they detect that you are non-human, they may not serve the entire page. But more than likely what is happening is there is a bunch of client-side rendering that happens when you view the page in a web browser, which is not being executed when you request that same page in scrapy.

Yahoo! Finance has a [API](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/). Using that will probably get you more reliable results.

Comment: Ok thank you for the info. The YahooF API is sadly not convenient for me as i want the news articles about finance and not the market data etc. Is there a reliant way to render the page fully  ?

Comment: I would suggest using some sort of [headless browser](http://scrapingauthority.com/scrapy-javascript) to render the javascript.

Comment: Ok i tried splash but it didnt help. I am going to try selenium but i was wondering when i desactivate js in a brower i still get the page correctly so i assumed that i didnt need to use such a method.